# How to update an array of structs inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a function `recvErrorCheck` (this is just a small portion of it) and I want to update the `socketStruct` I pass into it. I understand how to update `int`s and the `fd_set`, but I am confused because `socketStruct` is a `socketInfo(*)[500]`.

```
void recvErrorCheck(int result, int j, int k, fd_set *readfds, int* observerVisits, 
                    int* participantVisits, struct socketInfo* socketStruct){
   if (result == 0){
   printf("socket closed\n");
   FD_CLR(j, readfds);
   close(j);

   if(socketStruct[k]->type == 'O'){
    *observerVisits--;
   }
   if(socketStruct[k]->type == 'P'){
     *participantVisits--;
   }
```

then I call

```
recvErrorCheck(result, j, k, &readfds, &observerVisits, &participantVisits,
               &socketStruct);
```

as of right now, but this does not work in regards to the `socketStruct`.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: You declared the function param as an array of structures, not an array of pointers to structs.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, i want my socketStruct to update in my main function, so kind of behave like a global variable, if that makes sense.

Comment: You say `"socketStruct is a socketInfo(*)[500]"`. So do you mean that you declared `struct socketInfo socketStruct[500]` in `main()` and are now trying to pass it as `&socketStruct` in your function call?

Comment: Or, did you declare `struct socketInfo *socketStruct[500]` in `main()` creating any *array of pointers* or was it `struct socketInfo (*socketStruct)[500]` creating a *pointer to array [500]*? Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).